# "Skip" a Stream.read operation without closing the stream in Java

Tags: java, sockets, stream

When you have a stream, such as an `inputStream`, or `outputStream` and you use

```
stream.read();
```

It pauses the current thread until data is received.

The only way I know that can resume the thread is to close the stream from another thread, which fires off an exception and skips to the catch block.

I am dealing with sockets, where I have a thread that loops and gets data from the peer.
I was thinking of adding a `pauseDataThread()` method which would temporarily stop reading data from the stream until `resumeDataThread()` is called. However it's stuck on that line, preventing me from doing that until it receives another packet.

Is there anything I can do to "skip" the `stream.read();` line without actually reading any data?

**Edit:**

@SimoneGianni 's suggestion works great, but it eats up a quite a lot of CPU cycles unless you include a "sleep" in the loop (which may reduce transfer speed).

```
while(!stopThread)
{
      if (inputStream.available() > 0 && !pauseThread)
      {
           fireEvent(inputStream.read());
      } else
      {
           Thread.sleep(50);
      }
}
```

@EJP's suggestion also works great, but setting a timeout still includes the tiny risk of not *instantly* pausing the thread (therefore this scenario may still happen):

```
    > Socket timeout set to 50ms.
     myThread.pause();
    > Client sends data, it arrives in less than 30ms.
    //myThread still fires the event indicating that data was recieved, even though it was  
    //paused before.
```

I'm looking for a solution which will interrupt the thread.
This got me thinking though, is interrupting the thread really safe? Will it still actually read the line but not fire the event?

Comment: Well, looks like my only option is to just read that line anyway and stop the thread afterwards...

Comment: No there is not. I have had similar issues recently. If you don't want blocking you should use NIO. If you can't for some reason, the best way would be to have some controlling thread interrupt the thread your using to read. Try assigning a thread for each socket your are listening to to avoid blocking your entire program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a read timeout via Socket.setSoTimeout(). But it is customary to have a thread that does nothing but read from the socket, so it doesn't matter if it blocks. If you have something else to do, do it in another thread.

Comment: It is almost always a good idea not to do long running blocking tasks in your main thread. The only situation I can think of where it is fine to do long running blocking code in the main thread is in batch programs but then the original issue of the thread waiting for the data should not be an issue anymore.

Comment: @David Thread.interrupt(), but in my book you don't interrupt threads at all. I don't know why you're asking me: I didn't recommend it, and I gave you a superior solution.

Answer (score 1):

Normal Java IO is thread-blocking, Java nio has non blocking primitives for reading from streams.

However, you can use InputStream's available() method to know in advance if there are bytes to read or not.